# Running setup script in gunicorn prior to running WSGI server

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Say I have a module `setup.py` and some and flask application code in `server.py`.

Say I want to run `gunicorn -b :$PORT server:app`. But I want to run the logic in `setup.py` before setting up the WSGI server and running any other logic in `server.py`.

There doesn't seem to be any gunicorn flag documented that let's me do this (unless I'm missing something). Basically I want to do something like `gunicorn --RunThisFirst setup.py -b :$PORT server:app`

Comment: What logic is in the setup.py? Generally you should import it into the `server.py` and call before the app is initialized. You scope this in a function like `def create_app() -> Flask` and then call it `app = create_app()`.

Comment: There's a very specific use case I have that doesn't allow me to do that. `server.py` is coming from someone else and I don't want to modify the code in it. Just looking to make gunicorn run the code in `setup.py` prior to executing `server.py`

Comment: I believe I found a solution to your problem, see answer below. Looks like you're a new contributor so check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help prevent other users from -1 your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `gunicorn.conf.py` file should do the trick.

```py
import multiprocessing
import os

###########
# INSERT / IMPORT setup code
#
# maybe like this...
#
# from src.setup import run_setup
#
# run_setup()
###########

port = os.getenv("PORT", 8000)
bind = f"127.0.0.1:{port}" 
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
```

Running server:

```sh
gunicorn --check-config server:app
```

In your unique use case you may need to direct `gunicorn` where to find it (see [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#config)):

```sh
gunicorn -c /path/to/gunicorn.config.py server:app
```

Link to docs related to using `gunicorn.config.py`: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#configuration-file